# mongoose/mongodb query get last document from each sender inside javascript array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Schema

```
var chatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    sender:String,
    to:String,
    msg:String,
    msgType: Number,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

and a model

```
var Chat = mongoose.model('Message', chatSchema);
```

Besides that, I also have an array of IDs/names

```
var idArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I want to make a query, to get the last document from each sender from idArray

```
var query = Chat.find(
        {from: { $in: friendsOnline }},
        {created: { $last: "$created" }}
        });

query.exec(function (err,result){
        if(err){ console.log("Query error.");}
        else{
            if(result!=null) {console.log(JSON.stringify(result));}
            else{console.log('No results.');}
        }
});
```

Something like this, but this obviously doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each sender from idArray, you would need to find by sender, limit to 1 document, and sort by created time:

```
var query = Chat.find({ 
    sender: idArray[0]
}).
limit(1).
sort( { created: -1 } ).
exec(yourCallback)
```